# File Becomes Empty After Overwriting It

Tags: java, arrays, file-handling

so I have written a code in my project where I have stored some votes in rows in a separate file. I then read that file and extract the votes in rows into a 1D array, then I have to increment them like if the user enters 1, 1 vote is added to the first row, if the user enters 2, one vote is incremented to the 2 row and so on. After that, I have to store that incremented array with added votes to the same file (overwrite) from where they were originally extracted.

I am facing two issues, first, when the user enters 1, there are actually 7 increments done because the loop runs for 7 times as the array length is 7. The second issue is, after the file is overwritten, it shows results with incremented votes in the output but the file becomes empty and when it is run again, it shows 0,0,0,0 .... even after using output.close() at the end.

Please suggest, I have to submit the project tomorrow and there is still a lot to write, if someone could please lend 2,3 hours to help too would be great.

```
public static int[] voteCasting(String resultFile) {

     String[] votesArray = new String[7];
     int[] votesConverted = new int[votesArray.length];

     try {
         String partyVotes = "";
         int castedVotes;

         int i = 0;

         Scanner uI = new Scanner(System.in);
         Scanner rF = new Scanner (new File(resultFile));


         int userInput = uI.nextInt();

         while (rF.hasNext()) {
             partyVotes = rF.next();
             votesArray[i]= partyVotes;
             votesConverted[i] = Integer.parseInt(votesArray[i]);
             i++;
             if (userInput == 1) {
                 votesConverted[0] = ++votesConverted[0];

             }
             else if (userInput == 2) {
                 votesConverted[1] = votesConverted[1]++;
             }
             else if (userInput == 3) {
                 votesConverted[2] = votesConverted[2]++;
             }
             else if (userInput == 4) {
                 votesConverted[3] = votesConverted[3]++;
             }
             else if (userInput == 5) {
                 votesConverted[4] = votesConverted[5]++;
             }
             else if (userInput == 6) {
                 votesConverted[6] = votesConverted[6]++;
             }
             else if (userInput == 7) {
                 votesConverted[7] = votesConverted[7]++;
             }

         }

         PrintWriter wF = new PrintWriter(resultFile);

         while ( rF.hasNext()) {
             wF.write(votesConverted[i]);
             i++;
         }
         wF.flush();
         wF.close();


     } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(ProjectTesting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     return votesConverted;
 }
```

Comment: Why do you believe the second `while ( rF.hasNext())` will ever loop? You already exhausted all tokens from `rf`, so after `rF.hasNext()` returns false and ends the first loop, why do you believe it'll suddenly return true just because you call it again?

Comment: what do I do? ....

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting like this does not work - when the file is opened for writing, it is actually emptied. This does not happen when the file is opened for appending, but this does not seem like you want it. You need to write to a different file, then at the end remove the original file and move the new file to its location.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Appending is also what I can do, I just need to update my votes in the previous file with +1 increment, be it with overwriting or appending.

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies with this loop:

```
while ( rF.hasNext()) {
   wF.write(votesConverted[i]);
   i++;
 }
```

in previous loop `rF.hasNext()` already false.

```
...
while (rF.hasNext()) {
   partyVotes = rF.next();
   votesArray[i]= partyVotes;
....
```

so there was nothing to write. instead you could try:

```
i=0;
while ( i<7) {
   wF.write(votesConverted[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it stored these symbols in the file "
#"